# Staging and Production on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm sharing the same cluster for 2 *namespaces*: **staging** and **production**. The only differences among the two namespaces are:

1. Volumes mounted to certain pods (separate persistence between **staging** and **production**, obviously!)
2. A couple of web-URLs for relative addressing
3. A couple of IPs to databases used for sophisticated persistence

I have managed to address *(2)* and *(3)* as follows, so as to maintain a single *YAML* file for all *ReplicationControllers*:

- Use *ConfigMaps* local to a namespace to define any configuration that is passed via environment variables into the pods
- Use *Services* with *Endpoints* to handle a DNS entry pointing to different internal IPs

However, I'm unable to find a satisfactory way to have  a reference for a ***gcePersistentDisk***'s ***pdName*** - I can't seem to use a *ConfigMap*, hence a little stumped. What would be the appropriate way to go about this? The best alternative seems to be to maintain 2 separate *YAML* files with different strings, but this has a code-smell as it is violating *DRY*.

Also, any constructive commentary on the rest of my setup as mentioned above is highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably create one [PersistentVolumeClaim](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims) in each namespace. Take a look at [Can a PVC be bound to a specific PV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282704/can-a-pvc-be-bound-to-a-specific-pv/) on how to "pre-bind" PersistentVolumes to PersistentVolumeClaims.

Might not be an ideal solution but it probably works 'till PVCs support label selectors.

Comment: +1 Had completely missed on `PersistentVolumeClaim`s while reading the docs! Is there a way to pipe a file into `kubectl create`? That way we could do simple string replacements through a "top-level" command instead of jumping through these hoops

Comment: I think `mustache` run in CLI is ideal, given you can place your shtuff in a nice JSON file :-) https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache