# How to reattach released PersistentVolume in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset

Here is my overall goal:

- Have a MongoDB running
- Persist the data through pod failures / updates etc

The approach I’ve taken:

- K8S Provider: Digital Ocean
- Nodes: 3
- Create a PVC
- Create a headless Service
- Create a StatefulSet

Here’s a dumbed down version of the config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: some-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: some-headless-service
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    name: my-app-database
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: my-app
    tier: database
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: my-app-database
  labels:
    app: my-app
    tier: database
spec:
  serviceName: some-headless-service
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
      tier: database
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
        tier: database
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app-database
        image: mongo:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: some-volume
          mountPath: /data
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
          name: my-app-database
      volumes:
      - name: some-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: some-pvc
```

This is working as expected. I can spin down the replicas to 0:

`kubectl scale —replicas=0 statefulset/my-app-database`

Spin it back up:

`kubectl scale —replicas=1 statefulset/my-app-database`

And the data will persist..

But one time, as I was messing around by scaling the statefulset up and down, I was met with this error:

```
Volume is already exclusively attached to one node and can't be attached to another
```

Being new to k8s, I deleted the PVC and “recreated” the same one:

```
kubectl delete pvc some-pvc
kubectl apply -f persistent-volume-claims/
```

The `statefulset` spun back up with a new PV and the old PV was deleted as the `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` was set to `Delete` by default.

I set this new PV `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` to `Retain` to ensure that the data would not be automatically removed.. and I realized: I’m not sure how I’d reclaim that PV. Earlier to get through the “volume attachment” error, I deleted the PVC, which will just create another new PV with the setup I have, and now I’m left with my data in that `Released` PV.

My main questions are:

- Does this overall sound like the right approach for my goal?
- Should I look into adding a `claimRef` to the dynamically created PV and then recreating a new PVC with that claimRef, as mentioned here: [Can a PVC be bound to a specific PV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282704/can-a-pvc-be-bound-to-a-specific-pv/34323691#34323691)
- Should I be trying to get that fresh `statefulset` PVC to actually use that old PV?
- Would it make sense to try to reattach the old PV to the correct node, and how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If your want to use `StatefulSet` with scalability, your storage should also support this, there are two way to handle this:

- If `do-block-storage` storage class supprt `ReadWriteMany`, then put all pod's data in single volume.
- Each pod use a different volume, add `volumeClaimTemplate` to your `StatefulSet.spec`, 
  then k8s will create PVC like `some-pvc-{statefulset_name}-{idx}` automatically:

```
spec:
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: some-pvc
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
      storageClassName: do-block-storage
```

**Update:**

`StatefulSet` replicas **Must** deploy with [mongodb replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/), then each pod in `StatefulSet` will has same data storage.

So when container run `mongod` command, you must add option `--replSet={name}`. when all pods up, execute command `rs.initiate()` to tell mongodb how to handle data replication. When you scale up or down `StatefulSet`, execute command `rs.add()` or `rs.remove()` to tell mongodb members has changed.

Comment: For now the DigitalOcean `do-block-storage` `StorageClass` only supports `ReadWriteOnce` at this time (20190530). I need to do some more reading about using different volumes via the `volumeClaimTemplates`, it's confusing to me that I could keep MongoDB collections spread across different volumes but that the `StatefulSet` and all it's replicas would treat it as one source.. is that how it's portrayed to work?

Comment: `Replicas` only make service `Load Balance` request to each pod, so it's different from data replication. To make data replication, you should use mongodb replication. See **Update** for more detail.

Comment: How do you reattach a PV? This doesn't seem to answer to the main question