# Installing gitlab - PVs get bounded incorrectly, externalIP causes error

Tags: gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I'm attempting to install **Gitlab**, using **Helm**, to **OpenShift 3.11**.

To do this, I'm trying to follow the Gitlab documentation, and also trying some of the examples.

## Helm commands

I'm running Helm from an Ansible playbook. The task that I use to run the Helm commands is:

```
- name: Install Gitlab using Helm
  command: "{{ item }} "    
  loop:
      - "helm repo add gitlab https://gitlab-charts.s3.amazonaws.com/ --ca-file=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
      - "helm repo update"
      - "helm install  gitlab/gitlab -f /home/{{ ansible_ssh_user }}/files/gitlab-customize.yaml --name gitlab"
```

## Problems

### Persistent Volumes

Persistent volume claims are binding to the incorrect Persistent Volumes.

After running `helm install` then running `oc get pv` I see the following (notice how the claims are not being bound to the correct PV):

```
NAME                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM                                   STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
gitlab-minio                10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound       kube-system/gitlab-prometheus-server                             1m
gitlab-postgresql           10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound       kube-system/gitlab-postgresql                                    1m
gitlab-prometheus-server    10Gi       RWO            Retain           Available                                                                    1m
repo-data-gitlab-gitaly-0   50Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound       kube-system/repo-data-gitlab-gitaly-0   

                     1m
```

I saw this example - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/blob/master/examples/storage/use_manual_volumes.yml - that shows by adding the following in the Helm values file, I could remedy this issue - however it hasnt made any difference:

```
gitlab:
  gitaly:
    persistence:
      volumeName: repo-data-gitlab-gitaly-0



postgresql:
  persistence:
    volumeName: gitlab-postgresql
minio:
  persistence:
    volumeName: gitlab-minio
redis:
  persistence:
    volumeName: gitlab-redis
```

## Question??

How can I install gitlab in such a way that the Persistent volumes bind to the correct Persistent Volume Claims?

---

## Versions

### Helm

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.1", GitCommit:"bbdfe5e7803a12bbdf97e94cd847859890cf4050", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.1", GitCommit:"bbdfe5e7803a12bbdf97e94cd847859890cf4050", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

### Openshift

```
oc v3.11.0+62803d0-1
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://wallets-mgnt-master100.mgmt.wallets:8443
openshift v3.11.0+bd0bee4-337
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
```

### Gitlab

- Chart: gitlab-2.5.1
- App: 12.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the following, ansible task:

```
- name: "Create PersistentVolume for each gitlab component"
    k8s:
      name: "{{ item[0] | lower }}"
      state: present
      definition:
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: PersistentVolume
        metadata:
          namespace: kube-system
          name: "{{ item[0] | lower }}"
          labels:
            app: "{{ item[1] }}"
        spec:
          accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
          capacity:
            storage: "{{ item[2] }}"
          hostPath:
            path: "/{{ansible_env.PV_HOST_DIRECTORY}}/{{  item[0] | lower }}"
          persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
          claimRef:
            namespace: kube-system
            name: "{{ item[0] | lower }}"
    loop:
        - [ 'gitlab-minio', 'minio', '10Gi' ]
        - [ 'gitlab-postgresql', 'postgresql', '10Gi']
        - [ 'gitlab-prometheus-server', 'prometheus', '10Gi']
        - [ 'repo-data-gitlab-gitaly-0', 'gitlab', '50Gi']
        - [ 'gitlab-redis', 'gitlab-redis', '5Gi']
```

Note, the use of `claimRef`, which is used to bind to the PVC.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323691/265119 for a good explanation.