# AWS EFS Create a folder via AWS UI or CLI

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-efs

I have a kubernetes `PersistentVolume` resource defined which uses the `efs.csi.aws.com` driver. My question is, I want to specify the target path for this volume (`/app_data`). But this folder needs to exists first before I can start mounting them to the container with `PersistentVolumeClaims` otherwise it will get error that the target path does not exists. I thought that the folder can be created in the AWS UI or CLI when provisioning the EFS. Something like an S3 where you can create a bucket in the AWS web UI.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: app-pv
  namespace: my-app
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: app-efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-1234567
    volumeAttributes:
      path: "/app_data"
```

Comment: Am I right that the goal is to have `/app_data` dir on `app-pv` PV , attached to some pod by PVC?

Comment: yes. my workaround is to use `subPath`  when mounting the volume in the container.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a production like sollution but may work as workaround.
I would suggest to use initContainer for this task. You can mount whole fs in init container and create directory + assign access right there. Here are [example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51195446/2986553)

Comment: It becomes a chicken and egg problem. So even with `initContainer` you need the the `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaims` to mount it and therefore you will also get the error since the path did not exists.

Comment: yes, but you may create a separate persistent volume for init container with same fs-id but mounted as / for `initContainer`.  There you can call something like `mkdir -p /app_data` - i believe this step will be idempotent and even if directory exist it won't change nothing.

Comment: So I need to create a PVC also for that separate PV since one PV is map to one PVC. And how do I specify in the PVC to use this PV? I did not see an attribute to map a PVC to PV.

Comment: Especially I made similar configuration by mapping pv pvc with same [storageClassName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class) attribute - it is a string. But seems that there are  at least [one more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49785697/2986553)  way to do this.
Also I found [issue in github that may be related to your question](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/issues/6) and it is still open.